# How to consume COM object in ASP.NET class file

Tags: asp.net, unmanaged, createobject, com-object

I have a COM object that I am trying to wrap in a C# class in order to make it more readily available for other applications that wish to consume it.

I have the following code that creates an instance of the COM object, and then using reflection makes a call to a method to retrieve user data. This code works fine when it is located in an aspx page.

```
object jdObj = Server.CreateObject("jd_api.UserCookie");
string username = jdObj.GetType().InvokeMember("GetUserName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, jdObj , null).ToString();
```

However, when I move the code to a class file (JD_API.cs) in order to abstract it from the actual website, I can no longer get it to work. For example, I have the following static method that is declared like such:

```
public static string GetUserName() {

    object jdObj = Server.CreateObject("jd_api.UserCookie");
    string username = jdObj.GetType().InvokeMember("GetUserName",
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, jdObj , null).ToString();

    return username;
}
```

Unfortunately, the Server object is restricted to some ASP.NET libraries that are included by default in web applications, and so the above code was a no-go. So at this point I decided to try to create an instance of the COM object like such:

```
public static string GetUserName() {

    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("jd_api.UserCookie");
    object jdObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    string username = jdObj.GetType().InvokeMember("GetUserName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, jdObj , null).ToString();

    return username;
}
```

However at runtime I get an error that says, "*Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*".

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help on how to abstract creating an instance of this COM object to a layer that is not within the web application itself would greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare DLL functions within a class. Then define a static method for each DLL function you want to call.
The following code sample creates a wrapper named Win32MessageBox that calls the MessageBox function in User32.dll each time a .NET app calls the object Show method.
It requeres the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Win32MessageBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text,
        String caption, uint type);

    public static void Show(string message, string caption)
    {
        MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), message, caption, 0);
    }
}
```

To call it, just type:

```
Win32MessageBox.Show("StackOverflow!", "my stack box");
```

The method where you call the above line doesn't need to be aware that it's a actually calling a function in an unmanaged DLL.

Resources: the MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-536) by Tony Northrup.

Answer (score 0):

Hove you tried usinsing [interoperating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

I've done the following in the past (working from memory so you might need to fiddle with this a bit):

1. Right Click "References" in your project
2. Select "Add Reference"
3. Selelct the "Com" Tab
4. Find and add your Com Instnace

In your class file

```
using yourComName;

public static string GetUserName() 
{
        yourComName.yourComClass jdObj = new  yourComClass();
        string username = jdObj.GetUserName(someParameters);
        return username;
}
```

Hope this a) works and b) helps!