# Migrating classic ASP websites (includes Activex and COM objects) into ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, com, migration, activex

I have a website developed in old technologies like ASP, ActiveX, COM and some other legacy technologies. I want to re write the application in ASP.Net MVC, I'm not sure how to remove those ActiveX and COM and which is the alternate option to use for those components. Another pain point is i do not have the source code of ActiveX and COM dlls, So we want to re-write the application as earliest possible, can anyone suggest the possible option that how i can start migration.

Is it possible that i can replace the ActiveX components one by one ant test the functionality and re-write another Activex component?
Also can somebody share the materials/links to best understand ACtivex and COM ?

Comment: If you know what you _need_ (perhaps not even necessarily "how" because you don't have source) from those legacy components, then that would be an avenue for replacement. In other words, if you can answer, _"this legacy component provides ____ to my application"_, then you've defined a possible way to replace with .Net.

Comment: What COM components are you talking about?  Are they bespoke ones which were written for your website or are they standard ones which ship with Windows such as ADODB and CDOSYS.  If the latter is the case then ASP.net has its own means of connecting to databases and sending emails which doesn't involve COM

Comment: Not the standard one, this com dll's were written only for my application

Comment: This question might be worth a read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492752/how-to-consume-com-object-in-asp-net-class-file

Answer (score 0):

I have literally had to do exactly the same thing.

I want to answer your question properly:

> Is it possible that i can replace the ActiveX components one by one ant test the functionality and re-write another Activex component?

You could but that sounds unnecessary.

> Also can somebody share the materials/links to best understand ACtivex and COM ?

1. Create a blank ASP project
2. Set the target framework to be whatever (.net 2.0?)
3. Copy and paste all your files into this project, so that the web.config is in the root.
4. Now, to get your COM and Activex elements, right click the "References" folder and add reference. Goto "Extensions" and you should see COM modules there. You need at least the Microsoft ActiveX etc etc scripts. I imagine you have some lines like CreateObject('ADODB.CONNECTION'). You can search using the object explorer as to which COM modules contain which objects.
5. Tick them to include them, then build.

It might take a bit of fiddling, and there were some objects I couldn't find, and also some I had to download an install manually (but then after that they appeared in the extensions menu, so it was straightforward).

I managed to get an ASP2 project working in Visual Studio 2015 this way.